# How to create a modelform and save object in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

**models.py**:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
            return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class UserChoice(models.Model):
    user_choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_choice
```

**views.py**:

```
def index(request):
    question_list = Question.objects.all()
    context = {'question_list': question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

**index.html.py**:

```
<form method="post"">
    {% csrf_token %}
  
    {% for question in question_list %}
        <h3>{{question.question_text}}</h3> 
    
        <select hidden="" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-question" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-question">
            <option value="{{question.id}}" selected="">{{question.question_text}}</option>
        </select>
  
        {% for answer in question.choice_set.all %}
            <label for="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-answer">
                <input type="radio" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-answer" value="{{answer.id}}">
                {{answer.choice_text}}
            </label> <br>
        {% endfor %}
  
  
    {% endfor %}
  
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Question**:
How to save user choice using UserChoice model per each question using forms?

P.s. I know how to create simple ModelForm, but here my little knowledge about Django stopped me :). For now, I have no idea how to create this form, I read about **modelformset_factory**, but did not understand.

Comment: Currently, your question includes three questions and questions in SO are asked one at a time, so please focus on one problem instead.

Comment: @SunderamDubey thnx for the edit, left only one question.